# How to prove this following $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Question.** Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions which are continuous over $[0,1]$ and continuously differentiable in $[0,1]$. Assume that $|f_n(x)|\le1$ and that $|f_n'(x)|\le 1$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and for each positive integer $n$. Then prove that $\{f_n\}$ contains a subsequence which converges in $C[0,1]$.

**My Solution:** Here I try to use the following theorem from Baby Rudin:

> **Theorem**. If $K$ is compact, if $f_n \in C(K)$ for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$ and if $\{f_n\}$ is **pointwise bounded** and **equicontinuous** o $K$, then
>
> 1. $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded on $K$.
> 2. $\{f_n\}$ contains a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Now using MVT and the given conditions I have managed to prove that $\{f_n\}$  is equicontinuous on $[0,1]$. Now I have to prove that $\{f_n\}$ is **pointwise bounded**. Now $|f_n(x)|\le 1$ for all $x \in (0,1)$. So I have to prove that $\{f_n(0)\}_n$ and $\{f_n(1)\}_n$ are bounded. How can I proceed now to prove these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f_n$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ (and so is $|f_n|$), then
$$
|f_n(0)| = \lim_{x\to 0} |f_n(x)| \leq 1,
$$
and the same holds for $|f_n(1)|$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was posted before a correction was made by the OP. I don't know if you mis-typed the question but it is false as  stated. Example, $f_n(x)=x^{n}$. However, if the hypothesis includes the condition $|f_n'(x)| \leq 1$for all  $n$ and $x$ then you argument works: just use $f_n(\frac 1 2)-f_n(0)=\int_0^{1/2} f_n'(t) \, dt$ to prove that $\{f_n(0)\}$ is bounded. Similarly, for $\{f_n(1)\}$.

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh Please check what you have typed in the question. I don't see any derivatives in your question  and that is why I gave the counter-example.  However, I guessed you just missed a derivative so I gave a proof for the corrected version.

Comment: Sorry sir....I've edited it....